# Update Registry to Prevent Caching Window File Explorer FTP

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-registry, ftp

I need to use Registry to change the internet setting when installing software to avoid the Window Explore FTP get cache's old file. here is the registry location

```
Computer\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-87606484-4066434185-3981657551-1001\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
"SyncMode5"=dword:00000003
```

but I found that there have 2 location to change this setting and both changes will affect this registry

1. IE browser
   [IE browser Internet setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qnqZ.png)
2. control panel > internet Option
   [Control Panel Internet Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BpTN.png)

but after I tested, if I use IE browser internet setting or cmd comment to change the SyncMode5 registry value, the registry will change but FTP still gets the old file. and If I changed the setting in control panel to "Everytime I visit this page", after I press ok button, it will auto change back to "Automatically" in next time I open this setting, but If I change the setting in control panel, whatever the setting change back "automatically" but the ftp will only get newer file.

I tested in azure VM and local VM still facing same problem

this is bug in window or there are still other registry location where I can completely change the setting?